# php fluentpdo -> Undefined variable: fpdo

Tags: php, mysql, fluent

I am confused with the include stuff i think, I don't know where exactly its wrong.

The Connection file with fluentpdo

```
    <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/Mark20/libs/FluentPDO/FluentPDO.php');

$pdo = new PDO("mysql:dbname=ummah", "pluto","admin");
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_CASE, PDO::CASE_LOWER);
$fpdo = new FluentPDO($pdo);
//~ $software->debug = true;
?>
```

if i am using to insert data like this as below:
**Insert.php**

```
<?php
include '../connect.inc.php';

function inReg(){
    try{
        $values = array('name' 'xyz', 'pwd' => '1234');
        $query = $fpdo->insertInto('users')->values($values)->execute();
        echo 'success';
        return;
    }catch (Exception $e) {
        die ('File did not upload: ' . $e->getMessage());
    }
}
?>
```

Not a problem with above stuff, its just in a php file. What I am trying to do is use a class as i did below:
**Connection file** is same.

**DBInsert.php**

```
<?php

include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/Mark20/bin/connect.inc.php');

class DBInsert {
    function Insert($table, $values){
        try{
            $query = $fpdo->insertInto($table)->values($values)->execute();
            return 'success';
        }catch (Exception $e) {
            die ('File did not upload: ' . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}

?>
```

now i am creating object of above class and trying to call the Insert function like this:
**Test.php**

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/Mark20/bin/dao/DBInsert.php');

function Signup(){
    $values = array('name' => 'xyz', 'pwd' => '1234');
    $db = new DBInsert();
    echo $db->Insert('users',$values);
}
Signup();
?>
```

So when i am accessing Test.php i am getting the following error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: fpdo in E:\Program Files\Apache Software
>   Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\Mark20\bin\dao\DBInsert.php on line 15
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function insertInto() on a non-object in
>   E:\Program Files\Apache Software
>   Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\Mark20\bin\dao\DBInsert.php on line 15

I am new to php, not totally new also :). So a little help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks and Regards
Adeeb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Global variables are not in scope in functions by default. You need to do:

```
function inReg(){
    global $fpdo;
    try{
        $values = array('name' 'xyz', 'pwd' => '1234');
        $query = $fpdo->insertInto('users')->values($values)->execute();
        echo 'success';
        return;
    }catch (Exception $e) {
        die ('File did not upload: ' . $e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

or pass `$fpdo` as a parameter to the function.

Comment: This is the 4th question I've had to give this answer to in the past 24 hours. Why don't new PHP programmers learn about variable scoping?

Comment: In connection file i have this line $fpdo = new FluentPDO($pdo); Does that mean an object is created? and if as you said global $fdo will tht variable point to the object of connection file?

Comment: oh, so nice of you, i will have look at variable scoping once. Thanks @Barmar

Comment: But how come it is able to access in plain php file? But not in a class file?

Comment: You can't access it in a function, you can access it in global code.

Comment: But as u answered inReg function, I dont have problem in that inReg() function of Insert file, I gave that code cause its working, but its not working in Insert function of DBInsert file

Comment: It shouldn't work in `inReg` either, I don't know why you're not getting an error.

Comment: Its smooth no error in inReg() and data also getting inserted in table. If you get to know please explain. Thanks a lot, I used global in DBInsert class and its working fine now.

Comment: I can't explain it. I've been programming PHP for many years, and I always had to use `global` in functions to access variables that aren't passed as arguments.